# Azure continuous webjob fails in some cases

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs, continuous, webjob

I have a continuous webjob that is running on azure that after a larger deployment 8 hours ago gets the status never finished in some cases and in other cases completed the job.
I have enabled all logging I could find and have been spending quite a few hours trying to figure out what the problem is.

The only log error information I seem to be able to find is from the job_log which states:

> [11/15/2017 14:46:23 > e553e5: ERR ] Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
>   [11/15/2017 14:46:23 > e553e5: ERR ] at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Shared.Protocol.HttpResponseParsers.ProcessExpectedStatusCodeNoException[T](HttpStatusCode expectedStatusCode, HttpStatusCode actualStatusCode, T retVal, StorageCommandBase`1 cmd, Exception ex) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\Common\Shared\Protocol\HttpResponseParsers.Common.cs:line 50
>   [11/15/2017 14:46:23 > e553e5: ERR ] at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob.<DeleteBlobImpl>b__33(RESTCommand`1 cmd, HttpWebResponse resp, Exception ex, OperationContext ctx) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Blob\CloudBlob.cs:line 3349
>   [11/15/2017 14:46:23 > e553e5: ERR ] at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndGetResponse[T](IAsyncResult getResponseResult) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line 299
>   [11/15/2017 14:46:23 > e553e5: ERR ] --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   [11/15/2017 14:46:23 > e553e5: ERR ] at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndExecuteAsync[T](IAsyncResult result) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line 50
>   [11/15/2017 14:46:23 > e553e5: ERR ] at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob.EndDelete(IAsyncResult asyncResult) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Blob\CloudBlob.cs:line 1729
>   [11/15/2017 14:46:23 > e553e5: ERR ] at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.AsyncExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Util\AsyncExtensions.cs:line 114
>   [11/15/2017 14:46:23 > e553e5: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   [11/15/2017 14:46:23 > e553e5: ERR ] at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>   [11/15/2017 14:46:23 > e553e5: ERR ] at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   [11/15/2017 14:46:23 > e553e5: ERR ] at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Protocols.PersistentQueueWriter`1.<DeleteAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
>   [11/15/2017 14:46:23 > e553e5: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   [11/15/2017 14:46:23 > e553e5: ERR ] at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>   [11/15/2017 14:46:23 > e553e5: ERR ] at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   [11/15/2017 14:46:23 > e553e5: ERR ] at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Loggers.CompositeFunctionInstanceLogger.<DeleteLogFunctionStartedAsync>d__e.MoveNext()
>   [11/15/2017 14:46:23 > e553e5: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   [11/15/2017 14:46:23 > e553e5: ERR ] at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>   [11/15/2017 14:46:23 > e553e5: ERR ] at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   [11/15/2017 14:46:23 > e553e5: ERR ] at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.<TryExecuteAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
>   [11/15/2017 14:46:23 > e553e5: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   [11/15/2017 14:46:23 > e553e5: ERR ] at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>   [11/15/2017 14:46:23 > e553e5: ERR ] at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   [11/15/2017 14:46:23 > e553e5: ERR ] at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.TriggeredFunctionExecutor`1.d__0.MoveNext()
>   [11/15/2017 14:46:23 > e553e5: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   [11/15/2017 14:46:23 > e553e5: ERR ] at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Timers.BackgroundExceptionDispatcher.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0()
>   [11/15/2017 14:46:23 > e553e5: ERR ] at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>   [11/15/2017 14:46:23 > e553e5: ERR ] at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>   [11/15/2017 14:46:23 > e553e5: ERR ] at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>   [11/15/2017 14:46:23 > e553e5: ERR ] at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>   [11/15/2017 14:46:23 > e553e5: ERR ] at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Can anyone give me some ideas on how to debug this, because I am out of ideas.

My webjobs main looks like this:

```
 static void Main()
    {
         var host = new JobHost();

        var config = new JobHostConfiguration();
        config.Queues.MaxPollingInterval = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,30);
        config.Queues.MaxDequeueCount = 3;
        // The following code ensures that the WebJob will be running continuously
        host.RunAndBlock();
    }
```

and the processqueuemessage looks like:

```
 public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("importqueue")] string msg)
    {
        try
        {
            WorkerWebJobCore wwjc = new WorkerWebJobCore();
            wwjc.RunCore(msg, TableStorageAccessResources.ImportQueue,
                TableStorageAccessResources.TableStorageDataOneId,
                TableStorageAccessResources.TableStorageDataOnePassword);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            CommunicatorLog.Log.LogError("WebJobWorker","WebJobWorker","Error in processing queue message","ERRWJWF01");
        }
    }
```

So I have a catch around everything, therefore I don't get how it can fail?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently running versions below 2.0.0 of the Microsoft.Azure.Webjob makes it impossible to get a useful answer. 
When I finally got around to try and install that version, it pointed me to the issues with useful error messages.

Issues were related to wrong versions of dlls in regards to what the webjob core works with

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that something is either messing with your queue or with the files in the storage itself.

Looks like it tries to delete files that are no longer there. Or maybe something "larger" is being deleted.

Upon looking deeper into it, it might also be an issue with how you deploy your WebJob. Maybe there is a difference sometimes when you deploy? Take a look at these:

[Azure Web Job-The remote server returned 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32756357/azure-web-job-the-remote-server-returned-404)

https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/922

[Azure WebJob QueueTrigger message is not deleted from queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27359847/azure-webjob-queuetrigger-message-is-not-deleted-from-queue)

https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/645